# Fire the .xaml storyboard on button click

Tags: c#, silverlight

In my Silverlight application, I made a stroyboard manually through Blend.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<Storyboard x:Name="Swivel">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Menus">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="-90"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Menus">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I want to fire this storyboard in button click. Is there any way to do that without writing the storyboard in .cs and then storyboard.Start() etc.?

Comment: You can do `SwivelDissapear.Begin()` in your button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to tie a ControlStoryboardAction to the button's Click event.  [Here's a quick guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723988%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) on how to add the action in Blend.  If you don't see the ControlStoryboardAction in your assets panel, just add a reference to Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll.  You can find this in your Blend SDK folder (on my Win7 x64 system, that's in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Look into event triggers see [StoryBoard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979882%28VS.95%29.aspx) on MSDN.